# How can I find things in a table but not in the other in both directions?

Tags: sql-server, join

A contract can have several payments.
Given two tables t1 and t2, which both have columns contractID and paymentID as nvarchar(255)

1. I would like to find out the contracts in one table but not in the
   other in both directions.

   I thought of full outer join, such as

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2
   ON t1.contractID = t2.contractID AND t1.paymentID = t2.paymentID
   ```

   but the result it returns contains the results of inner join. So
   what query would you use?
2. for each contract that appear in both tables:

   I would like to find out payments in one table but not in the other
   in both directions. What query would you use? Could you automate the
   iteration over the contracts appearing in both tables?

Comment: Your full outer join here is missing the ON clause. Honestly just change your WHERE to ON and it should do exactly what you say you wanting.

Comment: It would be simpler to `union` the result of an `except`. Please limit questions to one question per question.

Comment: @SeanLange My typo. But  the result  of full outer join contains the results of inner join. So what query would you use?

Comment: If the query you have posted is the same you are running that is not the same thing as an inner join. It will contain rows from both tables and when there isn't a matching row in the other table those columns would be NULL.

Comment: Care to clarify - do you need query, which doesn't include matching rows? Then you can use condition like  `where t1.contractid is null or t2.contractid is null`.

Comment: Adding to what @Arvo said https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0be179de587ec5d9f6d675b4e5fd3f4b

Answer (score 1):

To give an example for your first question, which probably covers your second question, you can use `except` to find the differences between two sets:

```
with a as (
    select id1, id2 from t1
    except 
    select id1, id2 from t2
), b as (
    select id1, id2 from t2
    except 
    select id1, id2 from t1
)
select * from a
union
select * from b;
```

See this [example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f4176d73b973ea2c2976d6edb400ae6)